# How to create Start instance lambda function in aws using python?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

When trying to create a function lambda in AWS in order to start instance automatically, this is the function:

```py
import boto3
region = 'us-east-1'
instances = ['i-xxx']
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ec2.stop_instances(InstanceIds=instances)
    print('stopped your instances: ' + str(instances))
```

and after Save and Test - I got this error:

```
Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "2019-09-15T09:54:06.364Z 372c2df4-1303-4326-b882-a04154007881 Task timed out after 3.00 seconds"
}

Request ID:
"372c2df4-1303-4326-b882-a04154007881"

Function Logs:
START RequestId: 372c2df4-1303-4326-b882-a04154007881 Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: 372c2df4-1303-4326-b882-a04154007881
REPORT RequestId: 372c2df4-1303-4326-b882-a04154007881  Duration: 3003.17 ms    Billed Duration: 3000 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 81 MB  Init Duration: 115.73 ms    
XRAY TraceId: 1-5d7e0a3b-79a0391249fcda644105b8ba   SegmentId: 0eefbaed756a35c4 Sampled: false  
2019-09-15T09:54:06.364Z 372c2df4-1303-4326-b882-a04154007881 Task timed out after 3.00 seconds
```

Comment: Write your code here, not image.

Comment: And you do `stop_instances`, then there might be `start_instances` right?

Comment: Is the Lambda function connected to a VPC? If so, is it connected to a public subnet or a private subnet? Is there a NAT Gateway in the VPC?

Answer (score 0):

- Check if you have set the aws lambda `timeout` to some appropriate value, because it seems to be on the default value which is `3 sec` and looks like it not going to be sufficient for you.
- Timeout – The amount of time that Lambda allows a function to run before stopping it. The default is 3 seconds. The maximum allowed value is 900 seconds.[aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/resource-model.html)
- To start and stop the instance [boto3 docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/ec2-example-managing-instances.html)

```
import sys
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

instance_id = sys.argv[2]
action = sys.argv[1].upper()

ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')


if action == 'ON':
    # Do a dryrun first to verify permissions
    try:
        ec2.start_instances(InstanceIds=[instance_id], DryRun=True)
    except ClientError as e:
        if 'DryRunOperation' not in str(e):
            raise

    # Dry run succeeded, run start_instances without dryrun
    try:
        response = ec2.start_instances(InstanceIds=[instance_id], DryRun=False)
        print(response)
    except ClientError as e:
        print(e)
else:
    # Do a dryrun first to verify permissions
    try:
        ec2.stop_instances(InstanceIds=[instance_id], DryRun=True)
    except ClientError as e:
        if 'DryRunOperation' not in str(e):
            raise

    # Dry run succeeded, call stop_instances without dryrun
    try:
        response = ec2.stop_instances(InstanceIds=[instance_id], DryRun=False)
        print(response)
    except ClientError as e:
        print(e)
```